# Can not set CSS FlexBox to "row"

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive, livesearch

I have a live search overlay that has a flex container with three "results" containers which all three are also flex containers. Their children's flex direction works fine, but the results themselves don't accept "flex-direction: row" and just line up on top of each other in the search flex container:

```css
.search-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  right: 105px;
  top: 43px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(214, 224, 214, 0.94);
  z-index: 2;
}

.search-results-1 {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search-post-item {
  position: relative;
}

.search-results-1 p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 150px;
}

.search-post-excerpt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px !important;
  width: 47%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.search-post-img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  margin-left: -2px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container search-overlay-close">
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="searchcontent" placeholder="Watcha Lookin For?" id="search">
    <button type="submit" name="search">
    <i class="fas fa-search search-glass"></i>
    </button>

    <i class="fa fa-times search-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </form>

  <div class="search-results-1"></div>
  <div class="search-results-2"></div>
  <div class="search-results-3"></div>
</div>
```

and this is the css(there are three ".search-results" but they're similar so I only included the first):

I did not include the CSS for the FORM because it's "absolute". And finally this is the HTML that gets injected into every "search-results" container via AJAX.

```
<div class="search-post-item">
  <a href="pages/post.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>" class="search-post-img"><img src="files/thumbnails/<?= $post['thumb'] ?>" alt=""></a>
  <p><a href="pages/post.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a></p>
  <p class="search-post-excerpt"><?php echo strip_tags(substr($post['content'], 0, 100)); ?></p>
</div>
```

By the way the whole thing works just fine with "float". But I just want to make it more responsive.

Comment: try to remove position:Absolute

Comment: i tried it, didn't work

Comment: You set your `.search-container` as flex container, so all of his child are flex element also the form. So remove the floating elements and set a width of 100% for the form and `flex:0 1 30%` for the `.search-results-1`. NB you don't need to add multiple differente class if they use the same css styles

Comment: i tried it, still doesn't work. i even removed the form altogether from my html. still the same !

Comment: Hi, Can you add a visual (e.g.: screen, image, wireframe, drawing), something so that I can understand better what you're trying to do ? It's unclear

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can improve. Like when using flex you can use gap instead of using margins on the children (that often causes issues like yours). Also in your case you can use grid for the `search-container`. Also if your `search-results` is "the same" you can use a class with the same properties and add a "modifier class" for the properties that differs.

I removed the `box-sizing: border-box;` that should be in your base css and apply to all off your elements in the application.

**Box-sizing**

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Search**

```css
.search-container {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  right: 105px;
  top: 43px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(214, 224, 214, 0.94);
  z-index: 2;
}

.search-result-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
}

.search-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.search-results-1 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.search-results-2 {
  background-color: aquagreen;
}

.search-results-3 {
  background-color: red;
}

.search-post-item {
  position: relative;
}

.search-results-1 p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 150px;
}

.search-post-excerpt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px !important;
  width: 47%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.search-post-img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  margin-left: -2px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container search-overlay-close">
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="searchcontent" placeholder="Watcha Lookin For?" id="search">
    <button type="submit" name="search">
    <i class="fas fa-search search-glass"></i>
    </button>

    <i class="fa fa-times search-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </form>

  <ul class="search-result-list">
    <li class="search-results search-results-1"></li>
    <li class="search-results search-results-2"></li>
    <li class="search-results search-results-3"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, you are a legend! works great. responsive too! thank you so much

Comment: @eeeltie your welcome, accept the answer if it solved your problem :)